# xsl how to delete a lot of xml Elements under a parent using xsl

Tags: xslt

I have a xml structure like the below:

```
<Parent>
<child1></child1>
<child2></child2>
<child3></child3>
...
...
</Parent>
```

Let's say there are about 20 child xml Elements that need to be deleted and only keep 3 xml elements under the `<Parent>` Element.

I know that using the identity template for example the below template can remove one element in the xml file.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="child1"/>
```

But the things is I have to delete 20 xml child Elements and only keep 3 of them. How to make the code as less as possible to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out by myself. I did the following:

```
<xsl:template match="Parent">
<xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="child1"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="child2"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="child3"/>
  </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
```

And apply the templates on the parent node of `<Patent>`

```
<xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
```

Comment: Or simply `<xsl:copy-of select="child1 | child2 | child3"/>`.

Comment: yep it is the simplest way as i know so far to remove amount of children under a xml element